# Pygame Make text not disappear when colliding

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and I wanted to know a way to make my "Points: 0" not disappear every time the rectangle collides(Pontos: 0 means points:0 in English)

exemplifying what I said all I wanted to know is how to make the Point: 0 Don't disappear the first time and stay fixed on the screen until the game ends

code example

```
    if Rect_player.colliderect(Begim_Rum):
        screen.blit(text,(60,60))
        
        Begin_ColorShape = ((0,0,0))
        Y -= 990
```

if you have a lack of information, just talk.

begin_rum would be the cube that will start the game.and making the text appear

Rect_Player would be the player that will touch Begin_Rum making the text appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is just drawn if `Rect_player` collides with `Begim_Rum` and the condition is fulfilled. If you want to make the text permanent, you need to draw it in the application loop.

Add a state variable `draw_text` and set the state when the objects collide. Draw the text depending on the state of `draw_text`:

```
draw_text = False

# application loop
while True:
    # [...]

    if Rect_player.colliderect(Begim_Rum):
        draw_text = True       
        Begin_ColorShape = ((0,0,0))
        Y -= 990

    # [...]

    if draw_text: 
        screen.blit(text,(60,60))

    # [...]

    pygame.display.update()
```